# Prevent parallel run of jobs with same target in dbt

Tags: dbt

Using DBT cloud, as far as I can see the same job can not run in parallel (correct me if I'm wrong) which prevents contradicting actions on database. In my case I have 2 different jobs that write to the same target, for instance prod_run_all and prod_run_partial is there a way to prevent a parallel run of these 2 jobs?

Answer (score 0):

Most databases lock a table while a process is writing to it. So this should be handled by your database.

Comment: thanks!!, the problem is that dbt many times writes to a temporary table and then merges, so if 2 processes run in parallel it could mess things up even without writing to the same table at the same time